# How to Write/Read arduino flash memory with a selected address on arduino-due

Tags: arduino, flash-memory, arduino-due

I need to know if we can write to or read from an Arduino Due's Flash memory, without EEPROM, at a selected address. I know we have PROGMEM, but I am unable to write two strings at two different addresses.

When I write `Hello` into the Flash memory at address `IFLASH0_ADDR`, and `Hi` into address `IFLASH0_ADDR`.

I am unable to read these strings back out because the library `DueFlashStorage` doesn't work with those selected addresses.

Please, I really want to know how can i do this.

Comment: Nono sry it's for an arduino-due

Comment: Please post the code you have tried. Also Google [arduino due emulated eeprom](https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+due+emulated+eeprom&oq=arduino+due+emulated+eeprom&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.5873j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Here's the concept of EEPROM emulation explained in [Application Note AN2594](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00165693-eeprom-emulation-in-stm32f10x-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf), for STM32 microcontrollers, for instance. It explains the concept of how to use two flash memory pages for EEPROM emulation. Read this. Then, you just need to go find a similar white paper, example, library, or information from the datasheet or equivalent for the microcontroller used by the Arduino Due.

Comment: Related: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13038/how-to-read-write-variables-persistenly-on-arduino-due-no-eeprom-shield.

Comment: Read the datasheet.  Show your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this library: https://github.com/sebnil/DueFlashStorage.

Most basic use (copied from the above library's readme):

```cpp
// write the value 123 to address 0
dueFlashStorage.write(0,123);

// read byte at address 0
byte b = dueFlashStorage.read(0);
```

It emulates EEPROM using Flash memory pages.

Here's the concept of EEPROM emulation explained in [Application Note AN2594](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00165693-eeprom-emulation-in-stm32f10x-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf), for STM32 microcontrollers, for instance. It explains the concept of how to use two flash memory pages for EEPROM emulation. A similar paper may exist for the AT91SAM3X8E microcontroller ([1459 pg. datasheet here](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-11057-32-bit-Cortex-M3-Microcontroller-SAM3X-SAM3A_Datasheet.pdf)) used by the [Arduino Due](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/due).

### Related:

1. [Arduino Stack Exchange: How to read/write variables persistenly on Arduino Due (no EEPROM/shield)?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13038/how-to-read-write-variables-persistenly-on-arduino-due-no-eeprom-shield)
2. [AN4894 Application note: EEPROM emulation techniques and software for
   STM32 microcontrollers](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00311483-eeprom-emulation-techniques-and-software-for-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf)
3. [my question and answer] [Arduino Stack Exchange: Is it possible to use extra AVR Flash memory as non-volatile EEPROM-like Flash memory storage?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/51277/is-it-possible-to-use-extra-avr-flash-memory-as-non-volatile-eeprom-like-flash-m)